# What is the proper input format for drawtext's timecode option in fluent-ffmpeg (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to generate short video clips from 3 images with a simple millisecond counter at the top left per user request. So far I was able to generate the clips using the [`videoshow npm lib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videoshow), no issues here.

However, when I try to add the timer via `fluent-ffmpeg`'s `drawtext` filter to an already generated video, I run into the following issue.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ffmpeg('video.mp4')
    .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log("ffmpeg stdout:\n" + stdout);
      console.log("ffmpeg stderr:\n" + stderr);
    })
    .videoCodec('libx264')
    .format('mp4')
    .fps(fps)
    .complexFilter([
        {
            filter: 'drawtext',
            options: {
                fontsize: 15,
                timecode: '00\:00\:00\:00',  //<--- Issue is most likely here
                fontsize: 32,
                fontcolor: 'white',
                boxcolor: 'black',
                box: 1
            }
        }
    ]).save('out.mp4');
```

From what I found online I am quite convinced that my problem is with the `timecode` input format. Here's my error log:

```
ffmpeg stderr:
ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 585 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x1136 [SAR 923:924 DAR 130:231], 573 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7f91aa700700] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f91aa700440] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontsize=32:timecode=00:00:00:00:fontcolor=white:boxcolor=black:box=1'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Specifically this:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7f91aa700700] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one
```

When I run what should be the equivalent to my code in shell, it works perfectly:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 \
       -vf drawtext="fontsize=15:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=60:fontsize=32:fontcolor='white':\
           boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1" \
       -f mp4 out.mp4
```

I already spent a whole day trying to find any previous solutions to this problem, or documentation online regarding the proper format of `drawtext`'s `timecode` option ***within node.js*** with no luck. It seems most of the information out there is for bash/shell use. I need to do this programmatically on a server per request, and I just can't find the right example to solve this.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Strictly, this isn't a ffmpeg issue, but about escaping the timecode string. Attempt 1: escape the single quotes: `timecode: \'00\:00\:00\:00\',`. Attempt 2: double-escape the colons `timecode: '00\\:00\\:00\\:00',`

Comment: Thank you, a combination of both did the trick. That is, `timecode: '\'00\\:00\\:00\\:00\''`. If that was an answer, I would've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the enable option. If you wanted to play the video from 5 to 7 seconds for example it would look like this:

```
option: {
  ...
  "enable:between(t,5,7)"
}
```

Comment: if I add this `enable: "between(t,0,2)"` i get an error `Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing complex filters.
Filter not found`